# NSFetchedResultsController gives all entities back even not changed ones in NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having a NSFetchedResultsController that monitors entities that are coupled with an other entity. Now when displaying the entities in a UICollectionView I use a UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource.

The problem is that when 1 entity is changed the snapshot is returning all the items and not only refreshes the updated entity but all the entities. What can I do to prevent refreshing items that are not having changes?

**FetchedResultsController**

```
class func fetchResultsController(template: Template, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Counters> {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Counters> = Counters.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Counters.name), ascending: true)
    ]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ = %K", argumentArray: [template, #keyPath(Counters.template)])
    let fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                      managedObjectContext: context,
                                      sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                      cacheName: nil)
    return fetchResultController
}
```

**Delegate**

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
            didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
    var diff = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, CounterCellViewModel>()
    snapshot.sectionIdentifiers.forEach { section in
        diff.appendSections([section as! String])
        let items = snapshot.itemIdentifiersInSection(withIdentifier: section)
            .map { (objectId: Any) -> CounterCellViewModel in
                let oid = objectId as! NSManagedObjectID
                let object = controller.managedObjectContext.object(with: oid) as! Counters
                return CounterCellViewModel(counter: object)
        }
        diff.appendItems(items, toSection: section as? String)
    self.countersDataSource.apply(diff, animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

}

**DataSource**

```
    private lazy var countersDataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, CounterCellViewModel> = {
    return UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource(collectionView: self.collectionView) { [unowned self] (collectionView, indexPath, viewModel)
        -> UICollectionViewCell? in
        let cell = collectionView.deo_dequeueReusableCell(ofType: CounterCell.self, for: indexPath)
        cell.viewModel = viewModel
        return cell
    }
}()
```

CounterCellViewModel hashable

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.counter.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on Running application.I used to get the same problem when fetching new running sessions results to UITableView. I resolved it by loading data in to the new array and after fetching changed data to it simply changing and old array's content to new ones.

Here is the function:

```
func loadSessions() -> [Run] {

        var _runs : [Run] = []
        let context = CoreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Run> = Run.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "distance", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "duration", ascending: true)]
        
        do {
            let sessions = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if(sessions.count > 0) {
                _runs = sessions
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something happened while trying to retrieve tasks...")
        }
        return _runs
    }
```